# Using Attributes to Override Data Model Conventions

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We know that an application could have more than one `DbContext`, so when do add a migration, we need to specify which context we want to operate on as

> dotnet ef migrations add Initial --context XXXContext

so when we use attributes:

```
[Table("Colors")]
public class Style 
{
...
}
```

don't we need to also specify which context that the table exists in? For my example, there could be two databases(therefore two `DbContext`) and each database could the a table called "Colors", so how can I specify which context to operate on when use attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure an entity using attributes, that configuration will apply to any DbContext that entity appears in.  If you want to configure the entity differently in two different DbContexts then use the [fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties) configuration *inside* each DbContext.

> For my example, there could be two databases(therefore two DbContext)

Also you don't necessarilly need two DbContexts for two databases.  If they have the same tables, you can use a single DbContext for both.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to handle two databases in one application it would be the best to separate it in two library projects with the entity-framework implemented and one application which is consuming these libraries.

Example: You have two databases `Users` and `Companies` so you will have two library (framework) projects `User.Framework` and `Company.Framework` and when you add entities just choose for which database/framework it would be.

Your running application will consume these two frameworks and if you are using visual studio over the "package manager console" you can choose for which project you want to execute entity framework commands like `update database`. (Or `cd` to project directory to execute EF command with command line)